# what resolve for Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: json, kotlin, syntax

I get a json from the server as shown below and I build its classes in Kotlin as shown below, but on the Android side I get the following error:
JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
Is the class structure wrong or json? What can I do to fix this problem?

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "title": "\r\nXiaomi POCO X3 Pro M2102J20SG Dual SIM 256GB And 8GB RAM Mobile Phone\r\n۹۰٪ (بیشتر از ۹۹۹ نفر) از خریداران، این کالا را پیشنهاد کرده‌اند.\r\n۴.۴\r\n(۴۹۴۸)\r\n۳۲۹۷ دیدگاه کاربران\r\n۹۸۷ پرسش و پاسخ\r\nرنگ :\r\nآبی\r\nحافظه داخلی:\r\n256 گیگابایت\r\nبازه‌ی اندازه صفحه نمایش",
  "price": "100000",
  "cat": "4",
  "introduction": "",
  "tedad_mojood": "10",
  "discount": "20",
  "special": "1",
  "time_special": "1472645521",
  "onlyclicksite": "1",
  "viewd": "0",
  "colors": "2,3",
  "garantee": "1,2",
  "idcategory": "3",
  "weight": "10",
  "pic": "https://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/11/iPhone-13-PNG.png",
  "rating": "3.75",
  "parent_and_child": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "title": "مشخصات فیزیکی",
      "idcategory": "3",
      "parent": "0",
      "filter": "0",
      "filter_right": "0",
      "child": [
        {
          "idproduct": "1",
          "title": "ابعاد",
          "val": "500 * 500"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "title": "پردازنده",
      "idcategory": "3",
      "parent": "0",
      "filter": "0",
      "filter_right": "0",
      "child": []
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "title": "مشخصات کلی",
      "idcategory": "3",
      "parent": "0",
      "filter": "0",
      "filter_right": "0",
      "child": [
        {
          "idproduct": "1",
          "title": "تعداد سیم کارت",
          "val": "2"
        },
        {
          "idproduct": "1",
          "title": "وزن",
          "val": "10 گرم"
        },
        {
          "idproduct": "1",
          "title": "ساختار",
          "val": "فلز"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

clasess:


data class Detail(

    val id: String,
    val title: String,
    val price: String,
    val cat: String,
    val introduction: String,
    val tedad_mojood: String,
    val discount: String,
    val special: String,
    val time_special: String,
    val onlyclicksite: String,
    val viewd: String,
    val colors: String,
    val garantee: String,
    val idcategory: String,
    val weight: String,
    val pic: String,
    val rating: String,
    val parent_and_child: List<ParentAndChild>

)

data class ParentAndChild(
    val id: String,
    val title: String,
    val idcategory: String,
    val parent: String,
    val filter: String,
    val filter_right: String,
    val child: List<Child>

)

data class Child(
    val idproduct: String,
    val title: String,
    val `val`: String
)
```

Comment: that json looks right, but are you sure that that is really the response you are getting in your app? The error indicates that the json is not starting with a `{`

Comment: Also, could you share the code that you use to deserialize the data? Data classes are not marked with `@Serializable` so I assume you don't use Kotlin serialization.